# js, parse var back to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

i have two functions, the parent function is __triggerAction, than child function is __triggerNormal which the parent $current is being updated, how to parse the new

```
$current = $index
```

from __triggerNormal back to __triggerAction?

```
  _triggerAction = function(el, click, fx) {
    var $current, $link;
    $link = el.find('.tab-menu').find('li');
    $current = 0;
    if (click) {
      log('Trigger by click');
      return $link.click(function() {
        return __triggerNormal(this, el, $current, fx);
      });
    } else {
      log('Trigger by hover');
      return $link.hover(function() {
        return __triggerNormal(this, el, $current, fx);
      });
    }
  };

 __triggerNormal = function(thisEl, el, $current, fx) {
    var $index;
    if (!($(thisEl).hasClass("active"))) {
      log('current slide ' + $current);
      log($index = $(thisEl).index());
      __addRemoveClass(thisEl);
      __fxAction(el, fx, $current, $index);
      return $current = $index;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
return __triggerNormal(this, el, $current, fx);
```

do

```
$current = __triggerNormal(this, el, $current, fx);
return $current;
```

`$current` is not shared between the functions, so inside `__triggerNormal`,

```
return $current = $index;
```

just updates the local variable. You can just write

```
return $index;
```

---

Btw, the return value of event handlers is only used for determining whether to prevent the default action and stop the propagation or not. It does not seems to be necessary in your case to `return $current` at all.

Comment: Thanks, it seems right, but it still don't update the $current in parent.

Comment: Maybe you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo? `$current = __triggerNormal(...)` will update `$current` with whatever `__triggerNormal` returns.

Comment: i logged the new return $current = __.... but it returns undefined, Can you have a look here https://github.com/Devric/devTab/blob/feature/triggerRef/js/devTab.js

Comment: As I said, please create a functional jsfiddle demo... that's much easier for us to test. And please explain what your code is actually supposed to do.

Comment: this is a tab script, trigger action is called to detect if it is hover or click interaction, the trigger normal is used to catch the current <li> index, and perform tab transition, which it should update the $current after it finishes. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6daDT/ if you hover over the list, you will see undefined message in console.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that sometimes, the element is already active so, the `if` statement is not executed. You can either test whether `__triggerNormal` returns anything, or always return something from that function.